# How do i call an array from private methods?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, call, private

so, i have to make an application that creates results, i have completed everything, I think???? but i dont know how to get me private method outputData to output the array results from the private method getValue.

This is what i have

```
 // CreateResults.java
// Create poll results and output them to a file.
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.FormatterClosedException;
import java.util.IllegalFormatException;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CreateResults
{
   private int getValue()
   {
         int[]results = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
         outputData(results);

   } // end method getValue

   private void outputData(int[] output) 
   {

         for (int row = 0; row < results.length; row++) {
         System.out.println(input [row]);
   }//end for
   } // end method outputData

   public static void main( String args[] )
   {
      CreateResults application = new CreateResults();
      application.outputData();
   } // end main
} // end class CreateResults
```

Comment: can you please help explain exactly what that means.. im sorry im a beginner!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your code to work, you will need to make `getValue` public (and as it does not return anything, make it void)

Then within your `main` you can then then call `application.getValue()` which will create your array and then call `outputData`

```
public void getValue()
{
     int[]results = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
     outputData(results);

} // end method getValue

public static void main( String args[] )
{
  CreateResults application = new CreateResults();
  application.getValue ();
} //
```

Also as you `outputData` is working on the inputted parameter of `output` you need to change it to

```
 private void outputData(int[] output) 
 {

     for (int row = 0; row < output.length; row++) {
         System.out.println(output[row]);
     }
 }//e
```

Comment: okay, i understand what you are saying, and did solve 2 of my errors of the three. Lastly, the line   for (int row = 0; row < results.length; row++) gives an error on the variable "results" as it "cannot find symbol"  and yeah i changed the input to output like right after i posted, i just forgot to change on here

Answer (score 1):

Your array exists only within method scope. Put definition outside, ,make it class variable, like this:

```
public class CreateResults
{
int[]results;
   private int getValue()
   {
         results = new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
         outputData(results);

   } // end method getValue
}
```

Comment: when i did this, the {} brackets gave me an illegal start of expression error.  the line     results = (int[]){ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }; this line gave a lot of erros because of the brackets and i am having trouble understanding

Comment: Sorry. Right syntax would be: result=new int[]{1, 2, 3};